# Getting data from an ArrayList to then use in calculations?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, average, standard-deviation

So I have an assignment, and it requires me to calculate the average of each students marks for each assignment then to calculate the average of each assignment. I am able to calculate the average for each student but i'm having trouble with the average for each assignment and also for the average of averages.
Then i also need to calculate the standard deviation, we have been given an equation but i'm not sure how to implement it.

The final out put should look like:

```
Student Name     FAN      Part 1 Part 2 Part 3 Part 4 Mark    Grade
Adam Adamson     adam0001 85.4   79.8   82.4   86.1   82.77%  DN
Bethany Bright   brig0001 89.7   85.6   84.2   82.9   84.92%  DN
Cameron Carlson  carl0001 55.45  49.82  60.4   42.27  50.23%  P
David Dawson     daws0001 72.6   78.49  80.2   65.88  74.46%  CR
Evelyn Ellis     elli0001 50.2   35.88  48.41  58.37  46.57%  FA
Frances Fitz     fitz0001 78.9   75.67  82.48  79.1   78.38%  DN
Greg Gregson     greg0001 24.3   32.88  29.72  28.4   30.05%  F
Harriett Hope    hope0001 52.2   58.93  61.5   63.44  60.12%  P
Ivan Indigo      indi0001 88.4   91.23  90.05  92.46  91.08%  HD
Jessica Jones    jone0001 82.33  89.74  81.3   84.85  85.84%  HD
                  Average 67.948 67.804 70.066 68.377 68.44%  CR
                                               StdDev 19.4441
```

I have 3 classes, 2 are just defining the array for the student names&fans and then the other is an array for the student marks. They are not really relevant to the question.

I am basically running everything in my main class because that was the only way i could get it to format properly and i'm running out of time.

```
public class TopicManagement 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{   

    System.out.println("Hello, Welcome to the Student Assesment Calculator");
                                     //added an extra tab before the FAN to adjust for longer names
    System.out.println("Student Name \t\tFAN \t\tScore 1\tScore 2\tScore 3\tScore 4\tMark\tGrade");


    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");  //rouding to 2 decimal places
    DecimalFormat df3 = new DecimalFormat("#.###"); //rounding to 3 decimal places

    String [][] marks = StudentMarks.StudentMarks();  //marks Arrays is the students assignment results
    String [][] nameFan = Student.Student();          //nameFan is the array containing student names and FANs


    for (int row = 0; row < marks.length; row++)
    {                                          //ROW,COL
        double score1 = Double.parseDouble(marks[row][2]);  //parsing the data from the array into a double
        double score2 = Double.parseDouble(marks[row][3]);
        double score3 = Double.parseDouble(marks[row][4]);
        double score4 = Double.parseDouble(marks[row][5]);

        double average = score1*0.1 + score2*0.4 + score3*0.2 + score4*0.3;            
        String grade = null;



        if (85<=average && average<101) //if average is between 85 and 100
        {
            grade = "HD"; //High Distinction
        }
        else if (75<=average && average<85) //if average if between 75 and 84
        {
            grade = "DN"; //Distinction
        }
        else if (65<=average && average<75) //if average is between 65 and 74
        {
            grade = "CR"; //Credit
        }
        else if (50<=average && average<65) //if average is between 50 and 64
        {
            grade = "P"; //Pass
        }
        else if (45<=average && average<50) //if average is between 45 and 49
        {
            grade = "FA"; //Fail Academic
        }
        else if (0<=average && average<45) //if average is between 0 and 44
        {
            grade = "F"; //Fail
        }



        System.out.println(nameFan[row][0] + "\t\t" + nameFan[row][1] + "\t" + marks[row][2] + "\t" + marks[row][3] + "\t" + 
                           marks[row][4] + "\t" + marks[row][5] + "\t" + df2.format(average) + "%\t" + grade);
    }

     for (int col = 0; col < marks.length; col++)
     {
        ArrayList average1 = new ArrayList(10);
        ArrayList average2 = new ArrayList(10);
        ArrayList average3 = new ArrayList(10);
        ArrayList average4 = new ArrayList(10);

        double part1 = Double.parseDouble(marks[col][2]);
        double part2 = Double.parseDouble(marks[col][3]);
        double part3 = Double.parseDouble(marks[col][4]);
        double part4 = Double.parseDouble(marks[col][5]);

        average1.add(part1);
        average2.add(part2);
        average3.add(part3);
        average4.add(part4);

        double average = avera;
        String grade = null;

        if (85<=average && average<101) //if average is between 85 and 100
        {
            grade = "HD"; //High Distinction
        }
        else if (75<=average && average<85) //if average if between 75 and 84
        {
            grade = "DN"; //Distinction
        }
        else if (65<=average && average<75) //if average is between 65 and 74
        {
            grade = "CR"; //Credit
        }
        else if (50<=average && average<65) //if average is between 50 and 64
        {
            grade = "P"; //Pass
        }
        else if (45<=average && average<50) //if average is between 45 and 49
        {
            grade = "FA"; //Fail Academic
        }
        else if (0<=average && average<45) //if average is between 0 and 44
        {
            grade = "F"; //Fail
        }

        System.out.println("\t\t\tAverage" + " \t" + average1 + "\t" + average2 + "\t" + average3 + "\t" +
                                            average4 + "\t" + df2.format(average) + "%\t" +  grade);
      }
  }//end of method
}//end of class
```

this outputs:

```
Hello, Welcome to the Student Assesment Calculator
Student Name        FAN         Score 1 Score 2 Score 3 Score 4 Mark    Grade
Adam Adamson        adam0001    85.4    79.8    82.4    86.1    82.77%  DN
Bethany Bright      brig0001    89.7    85.6    84.2    82.9    84.92%  DN
Cameron Carlson     carl0001    55.45   49.82   60.4    42.27   50.23%  P
David Dawson        daws0001    72.6    78.49   80.2    65.88   74.46%  CR
Evelyn Ellis        elli0001    50.2    35.88   48.41   58.37   46.56%  FA
Frances Fitz        fitz0001    78.9    75.67   82.48   79.1    78.38%  DN
Greg Gregson        greg0001    24.3    32.88   29.72   28.4    30.05%  F
Harriett Hope       hope0001    52.2    58.93   61.5    63.44   60.12%  P
Ivan Indigo         indi0001    88.4    91.23   90.05   92.46   91.08%  HD
Jessica Jones       jone0001    82.33   89.74   81.3    84.85   85.84%  HD
```

The standard deviation we were given was (hopefully you can interpret):

```
SD = sqrt(sum of(each value in the data set - mean of all data in the data set)^2)
divided by       number of values in the data set
```

I'm not sure how to go about getting those last two lines, the average, and the standard deviation. I think what i have at the moment is each assignment being scanned into an ArrayList, so my question is, how do i then get the data in that array list to then be able to calculate the average **OR** how would you calculate the average? i'm open to any suggestions and would appreciate if you could give an example through code.

Thanks.

```
                                     **EDIT**
```

Ok, so i've worked out how to do the averages. I've used a method for each assignment and then i call it in the main method, this is the first of the 4 methods:

```
public static double CalculateAverage1() throws IOException
{
    String [][] marks = StudentMarks.StudentMarks();

    double sum = 0;
    int col = 0;
    for(col = 0; col < marks.length; col++)
    {         
        double part1 = Double.parseDouble(marks[col][2]);

            sum += part1;

    }
    return sum/col;
}
```

I'm still having trouble with the Standard Deviation.

I can't even manage to work it out using my calculator. Please help, or at least stear me in the right direction.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

For each column that you're trying to find the sum, mean and Standard deviation, create a variable for each column:

```
double column1 = 0; //Do for other columns
```

inside of the four loop add the value of that column:

```
column1 = column1 + <value at row>;  //you could also use shorthand column1+=<value at row>
```

Please note that the brackets are merely placeholders. (I'm not going to do your assignment);

At the bottom of the four loop is where you do your math, you already have a total, so use to calculate mean. Once you have mean, you can calculate standard deviation.

Comment: i have made an edit. Are you able to help me with that as well?

Comment: The standard deviation is described nicely on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Basic_examples